# Infer a type of a tree in a scala macro

Tags: scala, macros, scala-macros

Inside a macro, how can I ask the compiler to infer the type of a constructed tree?
I've only found Context.typeCheck, but that only checks the types but doesn't return the result.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you've type-checked the tree you can just use its `tpe` method:

```
scala> def impl(c: Context) = c.literal(c.typeCheck(c parse "1+1").tpe.toString)
impl: (c: scala.reflect.macros.Context)c.Expr[String]

scala> def mac = macro impl
mac: String

scala> println(mac)
Int(2)
```

You *could* also wrap it in an expression, of course, but there's no need to if you just want the type.

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out and I hope this saves somebody else the hassle

```
import reflect.macros.Context
import language.experimental.macros

def impl(c: Context) = {
  val tree = c.parse("1+1")
  val expr = c.Expr[Any](c.typeCheck(tree))
  println(expr.staticType)
  println(expr.actualType)
  c.literalUnit
}

def mac = macro impl
```

By wrapping into Expr you get the ability to query for the actual type. Any is there to provide a legal upper bound. Without that the infered type would be Expr[Nothing] and you would be in trouble. The catch is to wrap the tree returned from c.typeCheck otherwise the Type is just null.

Method `mac` just returns () bu it prints out `Any`-upper bound and `Int(2)`  -the actual type.